# QGIS find points that are on or near a line

Tags: gis, qgis

I'm trying to find all points that are on (or near < 10 m) from the lines in the below example.

These are two separate vector layers, I want to create a third layer, which is a subset of only the points on or near the lines i.e. removing the outliers.

In QGis I have been trying the following but have not been successful:

> **Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersection**
>
> **Vector > Research tools > Select by location**
>
> **Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location**

In the dialog boxes I've tried adjusting for intersection, and touching at different precisions.

None of these solutions gives the desired effect.

Any tips

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was what I did in the end, was a little convoluted but works:

1) Create buffer around road network and dissolve into a single polygon:

```
**Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Fixed distance buffer **
    input: Nnes
    distance: 0.0001
    segments = 100
    dissolve = true

rename layer: buffer_lines
```

2) Create buffer around points:

```
**Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Fixed distance buffer **
    input: points
    distance: 0.00001
    segments = 100
    dissolve = true

rename layer: buffer_points
```

3) Select buffer_points fully contained by buffer_lines.

```
**Vector > Research Tools > Select by location **
    from: buffer_points
    in: buffer_lines
    within
```

4) Save selected features as new layer, by right clicking layer, and tick selected features only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a buffer around the points. This buffer should be the distance from the line within which you wish to pick up points - in your case 10 metres. It will come in handy later on if you give each point a unique ID before this step (if not already done).
2. Take the intersections between the buffer and point layer. This will give you the sections of line which sit in these 10 metre buffers. The attributes table will tell you which point the buffer belongs to and which line it is intersected by.
3. Process in Excel to use the unique IDs to obtain which points sit within 10 metres of the line. You may wish to use a VLOOKUP() or INDEX(MATCH()) formula to obtain the point geometries from the original points layer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using "join atributtes by nearest neighbor".

- The first layer should be your point layer.
- The second should be your lines layer.
- IMPORTANT: The (optional) maximum distance would be 10m (in your case).
- IMPORTANT: Check the "discard non matching" - this will discard all that are farther than the provided distance

You may or may not actually join atributtes but only the points that fit your maximum distance criteria will be exported to a newly created layer.